# Can python leverage a java defined interface?

Tags: java, python, interface

We have one java project A and a python project B. I want to define an interface

```
public interface ISomething {
   ......
}
```

now we want the python project B to follow this interface to define their entity and provide the information. Is there way for python to import java lib?

If it can be done, should I define this interface in a separate lib project on java side, cause the project A is a big functioning project. However, on the other side, I am thinking it is a little bit too much for defining a lib project for this interface (of course, for now)

Comment: Your question is _way_ too vague. You will need to bridge Python and Java with a Python C extension + JNI, which is a major hassle and should really only be a last resort. Can't you couple the systems using a less invasive means like a network socket or temporary file?

Comment: You could exchange data with JSON or whatnot.

Comment: Integrating Java and Python on such a low level is very difficult and the end result will likely be unreliable and difficult to maintain. You should consider exploring other options, such as creating a web service in one language that you can use from the other.